# JMockit Troubles (just starting)

Tags: java, testing, jmockit

SO I have a kinda convoluted problem I will describe it with similar examples instead of copying TONS of code in. The problem comes in that I don't really know how to use JMockit well, dare I say properly.

I have an interface:

```
public interface IRsrcResolver {
 RsrcSet getForQuery(Query, RsrcContext, int);
}
```

There is a real implementation of it - it is kinda intense.  So I made a mocked version that just returns null.  I want to then set an [nonstrict]expectation that will return the proper values.  It changes test to test.

In code:

```
public class MockRsrcResolver implements IRsrcResolver { 
  RsrcSet getForQuery(Query, RsrcContext, int) { return null; } 
}
```

in the Test class I implement it and then want set the expectations (StateEngine uses the RsrcResolver)

```
    public class StateEngineTest {
      @Mocked
      public IRsrcResolver rsrcResolver;
      @Mocked
      public RsrcSet rsrcSet;

      @Mocked
      private StateEngine stateEngine;


      public void setUp () throws Exception {
        stateEngine = new StateEngine ();
        rsrcResolver = new MockRsrcResolver ();
        rsrcSet = new RsrcSet ();

        new NonStrictExpectations () {
          {
            rsrcResolver.getForQuery((Query) any, (RsrcContext)any, anyInt);
            result = rsrcSet;
          }
        }
      }


    @Test
    public void testSetState () {
      /*... does something that calls getForQuery (...) on an IRsrcResolver ...*/
      stateTest.doSomething ();
      /* ... assert assert assert ... */
    }  
  }
```

In doSomething there is something like:

```
  IRsrcResolver m_rsrcResolver = new RsrcResolver ()
  RsrcSet m_rsrcSet = m_rsrcResolver.getQuery (query, rsrcCtx, 4);
  m_rsrcSet.doSomethingElse ();
```

m_rsrcSet gets a null value and the debug shows it calling into the null MockRsrcResolver, instead of using the expectation...
Am I incorrect in doing it this way?  Thanks for any advice you may have!

Comment: So, you want to mock the method getForQuery, but what do you want the mock to return ? A concrete RsrcSet ? Or a RsrcSet whose method doSomethingElse is also mocked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMockit is not really easy to understand, because there is a lot of magic happening when we use it, and this can be very unintuitive (though very powerful).

In your situation, it appears that the class `MockRsrcResolver` is useless, since you want to mock a call to a method of `RsrcResolver` (which is instanciated in the tested code).

There is a misuse of the expectation's mocked variables. `rsrcResolver`, `rsrcSet` and `stateEngine` should not be given a value. They are actually placeholders for the mocked instances that JMockit magically generates.

#### Solution 1

Here is how I would have mocked this method, if `RsrcSet` doesn't have to be mocked :

```
final RsrcSet queryResult = new RsrcSet();
// (insert initialization of queryResult here)

new NonStrictExpectations () {
  RsrcResolver rsrcResolver;
  {
    rsrcResolver.getForQuery((Query) any, (RsrcContext)any, anyInt);
    result = queryResult
  }
}
```

Note that I declare the "mock placeholder" variables as member of the expectation, not as member of the test class. Maybe the latter works too, I don't know (there are many ways to achieve the same result with JMockit). But the important point is that I don't reassign those variables.

The above expectation means : "intercept every calls of the method `RsrcResolver#getForQuery` and return the `queryResult` instance instead".
Actually I'm not sure about the precise behavior, when using non-strict expectations (I mainly use strict ones). Maybe it means : "intercept calls of every methods of `RsrcResolver`, doing nothing and returning default values. But for the special case of method `RsrcResolver#getForQuery`, return the `queryResult` instance."

#### Solution 2

Here is how I would have mocked this method, if `RsrcSet#doSomethingElse` has to be mocked too :

```
new NonStrictExpectations () {
  RsrcResolver rsrcResolver;
  RsrcSet rsrcSet;
  {
    rsrcResolver.getForQuery((Query) any, (RsrcContext)any, anyInt);
    result = rsrcSet;
    rsrcSet.doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

The above expectation means : "intercept every calls of the method `RsrcResolver#getForQuery` and return a mocked `RsrcSet` instance instead. This mocked instance will do nothing when called". Of course, if `doSomethingElse` has to return a value, you can use a `result =` instruction.